# How to set default Font Size in Ajax ControlKit's HTMLEditorExtender?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I looked for solution on StackOverflow and elsewhere but didn't seem to find it

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/HtmlEditorExtender/HtmlEditorExtenderCustomEvents.aspx

I might be able to control how big text appears through CSS but I want to set the default font size value  in the  editor itself.

Comment: Do you want to set a default size as, say, 3, instead of 2?

Comment: Default is@MikhailTymchuk yes. Default is 1 btw.

Comment: There is no option for setting default text size for the text. HtmlEditorExtender uses default document settings.

Comment: @MikhailTymchuk any workaround?

Comment: You could try to attach to editable div `change` event and do whatever you want with the text area, but it's quite inflexible and erroneous solution.